# What step am I missing to effectively update a DocumentRoot?

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost

I am working on a new VPS, and I've copied over software from the development server to display at a subdomain.

At present, at least apart from tinkering with /var/www/html, I have not managed to get Apache to display anything else besides the Debian Apache "It worked!" page. My sites-enabled entry reads:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerName apps.example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /path/apps/www/
    DirectoryIndex index.cgi

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

If there is an issue with an index.cgi, I'd expect descriptive error messages (or display of the script's source code).

What should I be investigating to give this VirtualHost its own DocumentRoot?

Thanks,

**--UPDATE--**

I meant to ask how I could get the intended DocumentRoot to register. I looked in the error log and couldn't find anything.

**--ADDITIONAL UPDATE--**

The apache2.conf has:

```
<Directory /path/apps/www>
Options ExecCGI Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

The error message has now changed to:

> Forbidden

> You don't have permission to access this resource.

> Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) Server at example.com Port 80

**--ADDITIONAL UPDATE--**

The `Directory` entry has a DirectoryIndex of index.cgi first.

There is no change in behavior that I can tell.

Comment: It already has a document root! If you're having a problem, check the error log.

Comment: You still need to check the error log.

Comment: As stated in the update, "I looked in the error log and couldn't find anything."